# Conflation integration in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wps, conflation

I have a task at hand to provide conflation functionality in our software.

We are using JTS for other WPS operations. Open source JCS library is available but we need it as a WPS service integrated in GeoServer. I found that GeoServer has support for JTS, but couldn't find if it has support for JCS by default in latest version (I am using GeoServer 2.2.3). In case it doesn't is it possible to add JCS into GeoServer?

I found that a new **[WPS process can be added to GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html)**, on similar lines I added the jcs jar (jcs-1.0.1.jar) to WEB-INF/lib in GeoServer and started my jboss instance which is hosting it. However, after restarting jboss, the WPS GetCapabilities is not listing jcs processes. I am sure i am missing something here but don't know where.

I have the JCS opensource code; will it have to be modified to make it compatible with hosting in GeoServer as in the link above or is there a way where GeoServer WPS can upload an api and host it?

I am new to GIS specially these GIS protocols part but trying to connect the loose ends.

Comment: have you tried to compile the JCS source code according to the geoserver wps tutorial? I mean do you have applicationContext.xml and the given structure, etc? If yes and no error messages the problem could be that your classes should contain describeprocess and implement GSProcess, so they should start similar to this:     @DescribeProcess(title="helloWPS", description="Hello WPS Sample")
public class HelloWPS implements GSProcess {

Comment: No I have not modified JCS source code (its third party so using it as it is) but am writing a wrapper on top of it which has the required format(applicationcontext.xml, @Describeprocess and all) as you mentioned and include the jcs jar in it. Hope this works. Thanks for your input.

Comment: please let us know whether you succeeded or not